# how to save multiple sets of user settings?

Tags: c#

I have a small app with six sliders and I want to allow the user to save desired position of all six sliders in one preset. I use user settings properties for this but this way, ever next time the user decides to save changes on sliders, then previous preset is overwritten with new one, and I want to save all of them. So I was wondering how to do that. Is it possible to somehow make the list of user settings properties for each slider?

Comment: this is quite simple not to mention that there are many different approaches to this.. ever heard of `Google` tons of working examples on how to do this are already out there.. come on now.. you can navigate to Stackoverflow but can do a simple google search

Comment: firstly I agree with MethodMan that you should google it first and then ask a question here, secondly: if you decide to ask a question then be so kind and post some code so that we can see some effort and have something to begin with. I won't downvote and give you the chance to improve the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the question is quite simple, I will (try to) answer it anyway.
Let's say your sliders instances are stored in an array. The sliders all have a value from let's say; 0-100. When your application starts, you want to load the values from a file, if it exists. It's important to check this. If the file exists you can do a simple for loop, something like this in pseudocode:
    for(i=0;i

Then you can do whatever you like, change the values etc.

Then you simply save the file using a similar function
    for(i=0;i

I hope this helps you on some way, and I'm sorry but I've got to agree with MethodMan, you can just google it